# Link javascript from external bundle (noty) in Symfony, no AppKernel

Tags: javascript, symfony, noty

I want to use the noty bundle but I can not find a guide.
From my understanding I only need to link to it from the bundle.
In old questions, people recommend to add it to AppKernel but this bundle does not have *.php in the root path.

I want to keep the path of bundle and I don't want move to web folder.

Comment: can you rephrase your question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, noty is a **library**, not a **bundle** (I assume you're using https://packagist.org/packages/needim/noty).

A **bundle** is specifically built for Symfony, so the correct way to use is to include in in `AppKernel.php` as someone else mentioned.

A **library** is not specifically built for Symfony, so you just include it via Composer and then (since it's a jQuery plugin) you'll have to initialize it in your Twig base template and use it as you wish.

Comment: I am new in php/symfony. I thought that bundles could be downloaded exclusive via Composer, I didn´t knew about libraries.
Now I got to link library from twig this way:                `src="{{ asset('../vendor/needim/noty/js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js') }}" `  
But I think it should not be necesary to add the complete path to the library...  There is not a better way to link the library in the twig?